# Restore local git repo deleted by git rm -f

Tags: git

I assume my files are gone but I'll try to ask anyway.

I started versioning a directory that had nested another directory with local git repo in it(which I made by mistake some time ago). I pushed the changes to GitLab but couldn't see the content of the nested directory there and it had a suffix `@ 819bd776` in the name. Afterward, I accidentally removed the nested directory by  `git rm dir/ -f` ...

Then I tried to restore it by `git restore --staged dir` and then `git restore dir`... The directory has been restored but with no content in it. Is there any way to save the contents of that directory?

Comment: If that directory was a git repo, was its content pushed anywhere else ? (on gitlab, on another place on your disk ...)

Comment: Sadly I did not push that anywhere.

Comment: In your own repo : does `819bd776` match a commit known to your repo ? (e.g : does `git show 819bd776` display something ?)

Comment: It doesn't show anything, as the nested dir contained the .git file, it was removed too :(

Comment: *it had a suffix `@ 819bd776` in the name* - this is how GitHub and GitLab and others show a *submodule* in their web browsers. A submodule is a reference to (not a copy of) some other Git repository. Note that `git rm -f dir/` would remove only the *reference* from your index, but if the submodule's actual *repository* lives in the working tree and you remove the working tree copy (which `git rm` without `--cached` tries to do), that removes the repository.

Comment: This is why in modern Git, `git submodule absorbgitdirs` (and the initial clones *of* submodule repositories) put the repository storage for the submodule repos inside the repository containing the superproject. That way it's safe to remove the working-tree instances: they're not the actual *repository*, just *references to* the repository. But if you didn't do that (absorb the repository), it's really gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly not, git only saves what revision is checked out. The code after the @ is the hash of the checked out commit.

The only way to restore it, would be by using some kind of data recovery  tool, or if the submodule/sub-repo was hosted somewhere else.